# Mule HTTP Basic Authentication with intercept url

Tags: spring, authentication, mule

I want to implement HTTP Basic Authentication for my mule application which listens on HTTP and the URI is `http://localhost:8082/api/customers`. Lets suppose only POST and GET are supported.

I tried to implement authentication in such a way that

- If a user has **ROLE_ADMIN** role he can access both POST and GET endpoints
- If a user has only **ROLE_USER** role he can access only GET endpoint

I wanted to leverage Spring authentication manager for this purpose. I configured the authentication as below:

First I created authentication manager

```
<ss:authentication-manager xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" alias="authenticationManager">
    <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:user-service id="userService">
            <ss:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <ss:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </ss:user-service>
    </ss:authentication-provider>
</ss:authentication-manager>
```

Then I thought of intercepting the url

```
<ss:http auto-config="true" realm="mule-realm" use-expressions="true">
    <ss:intercept-url pattern="/api/customers" method="GET"  access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <ss:intercept-url pattern="/api/customers" method="POST" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</ss:http>
```

Finally I placed `basic-security-filter` after HTTP Listener like below

```
<http:listener config-ref="CustomerAPI-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP" />
<http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="memory-provider" />

<mule-ss:security-manager xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security" name="muleSecurityManager">
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
```

Now, what I expected is, a request from a user whose role is **ROLE_USER** (with `user/user` credentials) can only access GET and a request from a user whose role is **ROLE_ADMIN** (with `admin/admin` credentials) can access both GET and POST.

But I was wrong. A request from a user whose role is **ROLE_USER** accesses both POST and GET which is what I never expected.

Can anyone please guide me in the right way to achieve the above requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this example [raml-intro](https://github.com/MulePeruUserGroup/meetup-10-17/tree/master/raml-intro) to setup your api with spring-security. In this case, I am using the security.properties to manage users and roles.

As you can see in the those [lines](https://github.com/MulePeruUserGroup/meetup-10-17/blob/master/raml-intro/src/main/app/publishers.xml#L39-L45) I have a flow which handle security access but there are no restriction by roles.

In order to handle roles you can modify the code and add the following line

```
<mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

Your flow should look like this:

```
<flow name="get:/publishers:publishers-config">
    <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"
        securityProviders="security-provider"/>
    <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <set-payload
        value="[{&#xA;  &quot;id&quot; : 1,&#xA;  &quot;name&quot; : &quot;DC Comics&quot;&#xA;},&#xA;{&#xA;  &quot;id&quot; : 2,&#xA;  &quot;name&quot; : &quot;Marvel Comics&quot;&#xA;}]"
        doc:name="Set Payload" />
</flow>
```

Comment: I tried your answer. But I got an error during deployment: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mule-ss:authorization-filter'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations}' is expected.` What I understood from this error is we cannot have `mule-ss:authorization-filter` element inside `mule-ss:http-security-filter`. Can you correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement the authorization based on the Htttp Method, you can use the next example:

```
<ss:authentication-manager xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" alias="authenticationManager">
    <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:user-service id="userService">
            <ss:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <ss:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        </ss:user-service>
    </ss:authentication-provider>
</ss:authentication-manager>

{...}

<flow name="testingFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET,POST"/>

    <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
    <set-variable variableName="method" value="#[header:INBOUND:http.method]" doc:name="method rest" />

    <choice>
        <when expression="method.equals('GET')">
            <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="method.equals('POST')">
            <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </when>
    </choice>       
</flow>
```

Note that it's necessary to assign the roles ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER to the user admin because "mule-ss:authorization-filter" doesn't allow multi values.